# Flask web app, Node.js (queue) worker. Can't make docker work

Tags: python, node.js, docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I have an app with the following services:

- `web/` - holds and runs a python 3 flask web server on port 5000. Uses sqlite3.
- `worker/` - has an `index.js` file which is a worker for a queue. the web server interacts with this queue using a json API over port `9730`. The worker uses redis for storage. The worker also stores data locally in the folder `worker/images/`

Now I'm trying to make all this work using docker and docker-compose. Being a newbie at those, I'm struggling.

#### `web/Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.4-slim

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev imagemagick

COPY . /web
WORKDIR /web

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

#### `worker/Dockerfile`

```
FROM dockerfile/nodejs

COPY . /worker
WORKDIR /worker

RUN npm install
```

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```
redis:
    image: redis:latest
worker:
    build: ./worker
    ports:
        - "9730:9730"
    links:
        - "redis:redis"
    command: npm start
web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
        - "80:5000"
    links:
        - "worker:worker"
    command: python app.py
```

`docker-compose build` works and executes everything just fine.

Now this starts the redis server and the flask server but doesn't start the worker (I know this because I `console.log` in my `worker/index.js` and `docker-compose up` command doesn't print that).

So then I run `boot2docker ip` to get the IP address, and when I visit it, I get a `Gateway timeout` error but no error on the docker stderr.

I have been trying a bunch of changes to make it work somehow but can't. I really think it would be helpful if someone could explain what's wrong, and how I can make my setup work.

Comment: Did you open your boot2docker VM (VirtualBox) ports, as I described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29998490/6309?

Comment: I'm on Mac and I've never had to do this before for my other containers.

Comment: Did your other container involve mapped port that you had to access directly from your Mac host?

Comment: Well I just developed pypa/warehouse which comes with a dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. It worked without any mappings. I did look at their files and it didn't really make much difference.

Comment: If there is no port mapping, then there is no need to open port on the VM. But when you map port to your Linux host (which is the boot2docker VM), *then* you need to open port on the VM itself to access it from the actual host (your Mac)

Comment: @KaranGoel Could you update your post with the output of compose up (if there is any) ? Because nothing seems wrong with your Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  Going through a similar set up right now, would love to see your dockerfiles and compose files

Answer (score -2):

Use command -d to run in the background as the worker starts working initially and slee