# how can I connect to a docker from the outside host machine (mac)

Tags: networking, docker

I am new to dockers.

I have ran a docker container with mongo running it (using `boot2docker`)

`docker run --name some-mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo`

inside the docker:

```
root@8e9b742c127a:/# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2015-05-12T08:49:56.130+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-05-12T08:49:56.130+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2015-05-12T08:49:56.130+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-05-12T08:49:56.130+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-05-12T08:49:56.130+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-05-12T08:49:56.130+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-05-12T08:49:56.130+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
> show dbs
local  0.078GB
>
```

`docker ps` is

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
8e9b742c127a        mongo:latest        "/entrypoint.sh mong   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   some-mongo
```

now things get a little tricky since they require network knowledge.

**how do I connect to it from out side?**

tried:

1. `mongo localhost:27017`
2. `docker inspect some-mongo | grep IPAddress
   "IPAddress": "172.17.0.12",
   mongo 172.17.0.12:27017`
3. `mongo 0.0.0.0:27017`
4. `mongo 10.0.0.12:27017`
5. `mongo 192.168.3.124:27017`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/30183583/6309 (for Windows, but applies to the boot2docker Virtualbox VM on Mac as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Native Docker:** (*LInux*)

By **exposing** the port to your host via `-p 27017:27017` you can access the MongoDB service via the IP Address of the *Docker Host* itself.

Say if your Docker Host is `192.168.0.1` you could use that IP Address.

See: [binding container ports to the host](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#binding-container-ports-to-the-host) and [Connect using Network port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#connect-using-network-port-mapping)

**non-Native Docker**: (*e.g: OS X/Windows*)

**Update:** The above response is for Docker on Linux; If you are on OS X via something like [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) you will need to connect to the boot2docker Virtual Machine's IP Address which yhou can get from the `boot2docker` CLI:

```
$ boot2docker ip
192.168.59.103
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work... as you can see, I am running the container with ` -p 27017:27017`.  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you on OS X and boot2docker per chance?

Comment: yes, sorry for not mentioning that. i'll add it in the message.