# Connection refused when try to connect http server in docker daemon container

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am using boot2docker. I run one image at the daemon mode which starts grunt server at port 3000. This is the command I used to start it up.

That image has already exposed port 3000

```
docker run -d -P --name dummy image_name grunt server
docker ps
3af4ba19c539        image_name:latest   "grunt server"      54 minutes ago      Up 54 minutes       0.0.0.0:45000->3000/tcp   dummy
```

and then run into the same container to "curl" the web server.

```
docker exec -it 3af4ba19c539 /bin/bash 
curl localhost:3000
```

**It gets the html.**

However, when I try to connect it in my mac pc. It said "Connection refused."

```
curl $(boot2docker ip):45000
//curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.59.103:45000; Connection refused
```

I try to solve this problem by using VBoxManage, but it is not working either

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port45000,tcp,,45000,,45000"
```

May I know how to solve this problem. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Was the container running when you did a modifyvm? Because if it was, then a controlvm was required: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29998490/6309.

Comment: Log into the container and post the ouput of `netstat -ant`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I need to see the source of your application to be sure, but I'm willing to bet you've bound to the local loopback interface (`127.0.0.1` or `localhost`) in your application. If you instead bind to `0.0.0.0` to listen to all interfaces, you should find it is accessible from the outside.