# boot2docker, docker, django on mac os x

Tags: python, django, macos, docker, boot2docker

I want to run a Django app in docker on Mac OS X.  I have installed docker using the `get-started` tutorial.

I refer to the Django doc in docker-library to build image, https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/django, I add the Dockerfile in a new Django project folder

The problem is I build the image and run the container successfully but whenever I visit `container-ip:8000` or `http://localhost:8000`, it doesn't work.
Anyone have solutions?

Here are the images and container info; `docker_test` is my app

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED         VIRTUAL SIZE
docker_test         latest              fd6ceebc0c58        13 hours ago        761.5 MB
django              onbuild             9cbcfd71d759        30 hours ago        728.6 MB

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
cbf98a73ea0a        docker_test         "python manage.py ru   26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   docker_app
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> whenever I visit container-ip:8000 or http://localhost:8000, it doesn't work

See [docker/issues/4007](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4007): you would need to use port forwarding when using boot2docker on OSX.
That means the VM boot2docker needs to forward the port 8000 to the OSX actual host.
I [mentioned it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29998490/6309):

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port8000,tcp,,8000,,8000";
```

> If the vm is already running, you should run this other command:

```
$ VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" natpf1 "tcp-port8000,tcp,,8000,,8000";
```

[This script](https://gist.github.com/deinspanjer/9215467), for example, can help.

As shown in "[Boot2docker on OsX](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#access-container-ports)", `localhost` wouldn't work:

> The reason it doesn’t work is your `DOCKER_HOST` address is not the `localhost` address (`0.0.0.0`) but is instead the address of the boot2docker VM.
>
> Get the address of the boot2docker VM.

```
$ boot2docker ip
192.168.59.103
```

> Enter the http://192.168.59.103:8000 address in your browser.

Comment: I run this command but still can't visit by http://localhost:8000. But I can visit the django welcome page by visiting http://192.168.59.103:8000/. 192.168.59.103 is the DOCKER_HOST. So I think there must be something wrong  in the port forwarding on my vm

Comment: @wayne that seems expected: https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#access-container-ports. I have amended my answer accordingly.