# Connecting to a mysql running on a Docker container

Tags: mysql, macos, configuration, docker, remote-access

I'm trying to run mysql server on a Docker (installed with Docker Toolbox for Mac) container and access it from my machine running OS X Yosemite. The documentation from the official repo does not explain how to connect from outside the docker host !!

I've created a container using the [official repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) as follows:

```
$ docker pull mysql
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
$ docker inspect CONTAINER_ID
```

Then I get the ip address (172.17.0.1), but when I ping it I see time outs!!! What's the appropriate way to connect to the running mysql server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says:

> This image exposes the standard MySQL port (3306), so container linking makes the MySQL instance available to other application containers

First, make sure your docker run map that port: `-p 3306:3306` (or [the exposed port from the Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/c402b76d72d0089d6e84a2e24c143e99c3cb2919/5.7/Dockerfile#L45) wouldn't be accessible from the Linux host)

Then, you need

- either to add a [port forwarding rule to your VirtualBox VM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31353343/6309), and access 127.0.0.1:3306,

  ```
    VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" natpf1 "tcp-port3306,tcp,,3306,,3306";
  ```
- or access the boot2docker VM IP address `$(boot2docker ip)`, using port 3306.

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87581/discussion-between-elsoufy-and-vonc), it turn out adding the port mapping at the end is wrong:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest -p 3306:3306
```

This does not work because "-p 3306:3306" is just interpreted as arguments to pass to the ENTRYPOINT command.

This works (meaning a docker ps -a shows the container as "running", not "exited"):

```
 docker run -p 3306:3306 --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
```

Then `root@127.0.0.1:3306` or `root@$(docker-machine ip):3306` should be correct.

Comment: I'm not using boot2docker but the new Docker Toolbox

Comment: @elsoufy same idea: there is still a VM. Plus if the port is not mapped on the docker run, it won't be accessible anyway.

Comment: It looks like it works but I'm having a denied access for `root` I guess I have to garant remote access!

Comment: @elsoufy which solution did you use?

Comment: The one with `VBoxManage` but I think it's not working, I have another mysql running on vagrant and the client was connecting to this one and not the one on docker!!!

Comment: @elsoufy then try to connect to `$(boot2docker ip):3306` (if your docker run does use `-p 3306:3306`). With toobox, it might be `$(toolbox ip)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87581/discussion-between-elsoufy-and-vonc).

Comment: @elsoufy I don't see you in the chat anymore. Does it work?

Comment: I faced with similar issue and I could be able to solve the problem with docker command at the bottom. "docker run --name db -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yourPassword -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest"