# How to config fluentd with docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, fluentd

I am using a rails application now. In my application config file, I added this:

config/application.rb

```
logger = Fluent::Logger::FluentLogger.new(nil, host: '127.0.0.1', port: '24224')
```

Then boot app in docker, saw these error logs:

```
$ docker-compose up

...
sidekiq_1 | E, [2015-11-09T02:45:44.857664 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect fluentd: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
sidekiq_1 | E, [2015-11-09T02:45:44.860403 #1] ERROR -- : Connection will be retried.
sidekiq_1 | E, [2015-11-09T02:45:44.862926 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect fluentd: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
sidekiq_1 | E, [2015-11-09T02:45:44.864514 #1] ERROR -- : Connection will be retried.
web_1     | E, [2015-11-09T02:45:48.512481 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect fluentd: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
web_1     | E, [2015-11-09T02:45:48.512785 #1] ERROR -- : Connection will be retried.
web_1     | E, [2015-11-09T02:45:48.515245 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect fluentd: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
web_1     | E, [2015-11-09T02:45:48.515571 #1] ERROR -- : Connection will be retried.
...
```

My docker machine's ip:

```
$ docker-machine ip myapp
=> 192.168.99.100
```

My docker ps:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b5e980e1aa61        myapp_web         "bundle exec rails s "   About an hour ago   Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   myapp_web_1
43365dfb403f        myapp_sidekiq     "bundle exec sidekiq "   About an hour ago   Up 6 minutes                                 myapp_sidekiq_1
9570ee727f04        mysql               "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   About an hour ago   Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   myapp_db_1
e24495920c58        redis               "/entrypoint.sh redis"   2 days ago          Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   myapp_redis_1
```

Why failed to connect fluentd about sidekiq and web images?

---

## Edit

Add this to `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN mkdir -p /fluentd/etc
```

Add this to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
fluentd:
  image: fluent/fluentd:latest
  ports:
    - "24224:24224"
```

When boot app, log shows:

```
fluentd_1 | 2015-11-09 09:51:07 +0000 [info]: reading config file path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
fluentd_1 | 2015-11-09 09:51:07 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-0.12.16
fluentd_1 | 2015-11-09 09:51:07 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '0.12.16'
fluentd_1 | 2015-11-09 09:51:07 +0000 [info]: adding match in @mainstream pattern="docker.**" type="file"
fluentd_1 | 2015-11-09 09:51:07 +0000 [info]: adding match in @mainstream pattern="**" type="file"
fluentd_1 | 2015-11-09 09:51:07 +0000 [info]: adding filter pattern="**" type="stdout"
fluentd_1 | 2015-11-09 09:51:07 +0000 [info]: adding source type="forward"
fluentd_1 | 2015-11-09 09:51:07 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
fluentd_1 |   <source>
fluentd_1 |     @type forward
fluentd_1 |     @id input1
fluentd_1 |     @label @mainstream
fluentd_1 |     port 24224
fluentd_1 |   </source>
fluentd_1 |   <filter **>
fluentd_1 |     @type stdout
fluentd_1 |   </filter>
fluentd_1 |   <label @mainstream>
fluentd_1 |     <match docker.**>
fluentd_1 |       @type file
fluentd_1 |       @id output_docker1
fluentd_1 |       path /fluentd/log/docker.*.log
fluentd_1 |       symlink_path /fluentd/log/docker.log
fluentd_1 |       append true
fluentd_1 |       time_slice_format %Y%m%d
fluentd_1 |       time_slice_wait 1m
fluentd_1 |       time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
fluentd_1 |       buffer_path /fluentd/log/docker.*.log
fluentd_1 |     </match>
fluentd_1 |     <match **>
fluentd_1 |       @type file
fluentd_1 |       @id output1
fluentd_1 |       path /fluentd/log/data.*.log
fluentd_1 |       symlink_path /fluentd/log/data.log
fluentd_1 |       append true
fluentd_1 |       time_slice_format %Y%m%d
fluentd_1 |       time_slice_wait 10m
fluentd_1 |       time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
fluentd_1 |       buffer_path /fluentd/log/data.*.log
fluentd_1 |     </match>
fluentd_1 |   </label>
fluentd_1 | </ROOT>
fluentd_1 | 2015-11-09 09:51:07 +0000 [info]: listening fluent socket on 0.0.0.0:24224
sidekiq_1 | E, [2015-11-09T09:51:11.887833 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect fluentd: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
sidekiq_1 | E, [2015-11-09T09:51:11.888508 #1] ERROR -- : Connection will be retried.
sidekiq_1 | E, [2015-11-09T09:51:11.893544 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect fluentd: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
sidekiq_1 | E, [2015-11-09T09:51:11.893926 #1] ERROR -- : Connection will be retried.
```

It seems that ip `127.0.0.1` doesn't right.
I am using a docker-machine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `docker-compose.yml` has a `fluentd` section ([as this one](https://github.com/timstott/docker-log-drivers-adventures/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L12-L21)), with at least the port `24224` exposed (you don't have top map it unless you want to access it directly from the host)

Original answer (2015)

Then your rail `docker-compose.yml` `sidekiq` section should have a link section:

```
links:
  - fluentd
```

Updated answer (2021, after [battlecook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13429399/battlecook)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601843/how-to-config-fluentd-with-docker/33603061#comment117824118_33603061))
Since [links is obsolete](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#links), use [`depends_on`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#depends_on)

```
depends_on:
  - fluentd
```

See "[Difference between `links` and `depends_on` in `docker_compose.yml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658359/6309)".
Example: "[How to use Dockerfile to link main container to a db container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44993946/6309)".

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. I have did that follow your advise.  But when I boot my app, it shows: `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf (Errno::ENOENT)`.

Comment: @scho that looks like a volume which has not been mounted (http://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-from)

Comment: @scho by the way, are you using https://github.com/GoCarrot/fluent-plugin-sidekiq?

Comment: I am not using `fluent-plugin-sidekiq` now.

Comment: I updated my topic. Maybe the problem is IP address.

Comment: @scho What OS are you using?

Comment: @scho didyou port-forwarded the port of your VM (in addition of mapping the container port to the VM host)? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175164/6309).

Comment: I will try to do it. Thank you:)

Comment: I will leave a comment for those who will see the current question.
Since the "link" keyword is deprecated, I hope you use the "depends_on" keyword.
I referred to the following question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832095/difference-between-links-and-depends-on-in-docker-compose-yml

Comment: @battlecook Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.