# Links in docker-compose are not resolved

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379"
  myapp:
    build: ./myapp
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Dockerfile of `myapp`

```
FROM <BASE_IMAGE>
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["curl", "http://redis"]
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d --build` and then `docker run prefix_myapp_1`, I'm getting the 'Host is not resolved' error after 4-5 seconds.

If I change the Dockerfile, say, as follows:

```
FROM <BASE_IMAGE>
EXPOSE 80
CMD sleep 1000000000
```

then do `docker exec -it prefix_myapp_1 bash`, and try running `curl http://redis`, the host is resolved successfully.

Where the problem lies?

Comment: Have you tried to add the `depends_on` attribute for your `myapp` container: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832095/difference-between-links-and-depends-on-in-docker-compose-yml

Comment: @nwinkler Yes, tried that as well: `links`, `depends_on` and both together. Same issue.

Comment: Can you update your question with the compose you used that included a depends_on?

Comment: @BMitch Sure, done.

Comment: I guess is when docker-compose building myapp, the redis images haven't ready.