# Docker-compose depend_on

Tags: mongodb, docker, sh, docker-compose

I have a mongodb service and a test service running with docker-compose:

```
services:   
  mongo:
    image: myrepo/mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  test:
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    image: myrepo/elixir-tests
    command: sh start.sh
```

in the start.sh script i am trying to run:

```
mongo 172.20.0.10:27017/wc-app-sandbox --eval "printjson(....))"
```

but i get the following error :

```
start.sh: 10: start.sh: mongo: not found
```

My question is:
why does the error happen-
doesn't the *depends_on* property suppose to automatically include service dependencies? as mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832095/difference-between-links-and-depends-on-in-docker-compose-yml):

> depends_on
>
> Express dependency between services, which has two effects:
>
> docker-compose up will start services in dependency order. In the
>   following example, db and redis will be started before web.
>   docker-compose up SERVICE will automatically include SERVICE’s
>   dependencies. In the following example, docker-compose up web will
>   also create and start db and redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error does't mean "i can't find route to mongo container", it means "i dont found `mongo` execution bin.
Probably image `myrepo/elixir-tests` does't contain `mongo-client`. Try to install it `apt update && apt install mongodb-clients` into your container.

and mongo connection string should be looks like `mongo mongo:27017/wc-app-sandbox --eval "printjson(....))"`

Comment: getting this error `E: Unable to locate package mongodb-clients`