# Build docker image that depends on a local "Dockerfile"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following folder structure:

```
my_package
|- docker_compose.yml
|- a
   |- Dockerfile
|- b
   |- Dockerfile
```

Here, my `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  a:
    build: 
      context: a
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  b:
    build: 
      context: b 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

When I run `docker-compose build` I expect two output images, one for `a` and one for `b`.

Here's `a/Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN touch AAA
```

Here's `b/Dockerfile`

```
FROM <a> # NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE
RUN touch BBB
```

I would like the `b` image to contain two files in the rootdir, `AAA` and `BBB`, which requires one Dockerfile to depend on another.

Is this possible? Is there any workaround to make two Docker images (with a dependency between them) build in one `docker-compose build` command?

I'm stuck with `Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802` (which is compatible with version 2 syntax only).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `depends_on` in your docker-compose.yml, I know it is available in docker-compose YAML version 3, to express that service B depends on A and docker-compose will follow the dependency chain you express and build A first. See an explanation of depends_on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658359/1258525).

Since B is FROM A as your Dockerfile for B expresses both files AAA and BBB will be available in service B as long as the permissions for file AAA and file BBB are the same and in the this case you are running as root in both service A and service B when you execute the touch command.

```
version: '3'
services:
  a:
    build: 
      context: a
      image: a
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  b:
    build: 
      context: b 
      image: b
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on: 
    - a
```

Edit (by OP):

1. You can use `depends_on` in v2 too, but using an array.
2. Make sure to add the `image` in the docker-compose.yml to specify the generated image, so that `b` can be generated `FROM a`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I cannot install a newer Docker engine. I'm stuck at `1.12.6` and hence `v2` docker-compose. Also, I'm not sure how to add the dependency in `b`'s  Dockerfile

Comment: @Jedi, depends_on might be available for version 2 I do not know for sure. Also being stuck a a version is often times a sign of larger architectural system design issues, that need to be addressed

Comment: No argument there (about deeper issues). It's someone else's borrowed environment. Anyways, `depends_on` does exist for v2, with some syntactic differences (needs an array); however, I'm not sure how to make one Dockerfile depend on another (what does the FROM in `b/Dockerfile` need to be)

Comment: @Jedi the FROM in b/Dockerfile would be the image name of a service. you can set the image name in your docker-compose.yml for both A and B services