# How to use Dockerfile to link main container to a db container?

Tags: docker, containers

Docker has a quite convenient way to link the main container to a db container with a command like:

```
docker run --link db:db user/main
```

This is very convenient already. However, I believe it's still clumsy compared to a command like:

```
docker run user/ultra
```

where `ultra` is a container that is already linking the main container to the db container.

Is that possible that I can achieve this by writing a good `Dockerfile`.

I suppose I can start the `Dockerfile` with

```
FROM user/main
```

but how do I get the second container involved and then link them with `Dockerfile`?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess using `docker-compose` would be a better option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM user/main
```

That would create an image (`build time`) based on `user/main`, which is not at all the same as linking at runtime two containers together.

Plus, `--link` is now obsolete: see "[Legacy container links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/)"

> Warning: The `--link` flag is a deprecated legacy feature of Docker. It may eventually be removed.
> Unless you absolutely need to continue using it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate communication between two containers instead of using `--link`

Use instead the **[`links` directive](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#links)** in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

> Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified

You can make sure the containers are launched in the proper order with the [`depends_on` directive](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#depends_on).

Then a simple `docker-compose up` will launch the containers and link them on the same network.