# docker-machine osx port forwarding

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

How does port forwarding work with docker-machine?

I recently installed the docker toolkit and spun up a container. However I cannot reach it on my local mac as.

Is this [Port forwarding in docker-machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174560/port-forwarding-in-docker-machine) using `VBoxManage` the best way to access the running docker container using my OSX browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add port forwards from the command line to a running boot2docker VM use the following command:

```
VBoxManage controlvm boot2docker-vm natpf1 "default,tcp,127.0.0.1,1234,,1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

After restarting kitematic & the docker-host default VM. The container appeared in kitematic and the bound URL.