# Spring-boot app: Port mapping does not work in docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, port

I run docker on Windows7, make a simple spring-boot app, put it into image and run it in docker container.
When i refer to my app localy (http://localhost:8080) I see the response, everything is OK.
When I put it into container and run, it also runs in container, logs are ok, but port mapping doesn't works, and i can not receive answer from my local machine. Pls give an advice
P.S. Tried as well to refer from outside (not via http://localhost:8080 but via external local IP of my PC: 192.168.1.10:8080) but the result is the same.

```
dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD docker-spring.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

build: docker build -t springimg .
run: docker run -p8080:8080 springimg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker on Windows 7 uses virtualization to support docker-engine.

The port binding is currently on the virtual machine that runs docker-engine.

The virtual machine is created and managed with docker-machine.

Run:

```
docker-machine ip
```

to know the ip address.

Comment: Thank U! It works! And how can I map my local ip to docker-machine ip, if I want to refer to app from outside?

Comment: Through windows firewall, you could create a rule to map the virtual machine port to the hypervisor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Killed a day on it! Thank U!

Comment: you are welcome. Also you can let virtualbox handle this configure the mapping, there are several links which explain "how to". check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174560/port-forwarding-in-docker-machine